# Unable to apply addOnSuccessListener on fragment

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am unable to add any listener after the end of the onCanelled Listener
Actually, I want to do some task after getting data from the snapshot for which I need onSuccessListener and I am unable to add that

```
public UserFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user, container, false);


    myUserDataList = new ArrayList<>();

    userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/Users/");


    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                if (Objects.equals(dataSnapshot1.getKey(), userId))
                {
                    MyUserData myUserData = dataSnapshot1.getValue(MyUserData.class);
                    myUserDataList.add(myUserData);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    }); // Problem over here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` method doesn't return a `Task`, so you can't attach a success listener to it.

If you need to run some code after the data has been loaded, put that code into the `onDataChange` method. If the code must also run if the listener gets rejected by the server-side security rules, also add/call the same code from `onCancelled`.

So something like:

```
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            if (Objects.equals(dataSnapshot1.getKey(), userId))
            {
                MyUserData myUserData = dataSnapshot1.getValue(MyUserData.class);
                myUserDataList.add(myUserData);
            }
        }
        onResponseReceived();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Error listening for data: "+databaseError.toString());
        onResponseReceived();
    }

    private void onResponseReceived() {
      ... do what you need to do here ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I really needed this fix

I have one more question
Actually I need data from firebase where I need objects containing objects
therefore I need Arraylist of Arraylist to store such data.
Example
Link to code and JSON snapshot
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53466045/array-of-array-list-in-android-to-get-the-firebase-object-of-object