# Array of Array List in Android to get the Firebase object of object

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to calculate the average of each dish by their ratings and display in a bar graph, therefore I need the values of each dish with each thier rating

Example 3 people rated milk as {4,5,3} by each user from the user-specific node [linkToJSONTree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pSPR.png)

I need an `ArrayList` which can store multiple lists inside each index of its own listing:

```
private void letMeCalculate() 
{

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/Feedback/"+mdate+"/"+mealtime+"/");

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot i :  dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                stringArrayList.add(i.getKey());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

    for (String s : stringArrayList)
    {
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/Feedback/"+mdate+"/"+mealtime+"/"+s+"/");

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

               for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
               {
                   NewDishRating newDishRating = dataSnapshot1.getValue(NewDishRating.class);
                   newDishRatingList.add(newDishRating);

               }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }// end of for loop
}// end of function
```

Comment: This is totally different from the one mentioned as duplicate, Since I have query regarding object containing ArrayList of Objects and the one mentioned only says how to take 1D object array using List<>, mine is quite complicated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the solution instead of using Array list of Array List I can create genericTypeIndicator follow this link for the solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41503903/5867698

Comment: Using a `GenericTypeIndicator` it will not solve the asynchronous problem. [GenericTypeIndicator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/GenericTypeIndicator) is useful for resolving types for generic collections at runtime, so I don't recommend for this issue this answer for future visitors at all.

Answer (score 1):

When using the `stringArrayList` outside the callback, it will always be empty due the asynchronous behaviour of the `onDataChange()` method. If you want to use the `stringArrayList`, you should use it only inside the callback. So to solve this, please move the second for loop inside the `onDataChange()` method right after the first for loop ends.

If you need to use that list outside the callback, I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDZVV5CbQg)** for a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks since I get to know about genericTypeIndicator and it works good for me

Comment: @AkshayBengani `GenericTypeIndicator` has nothing to do with asynchronous  API's. That's the reason  Frank van Puffelen marked this question as a duplicate. [GenericTypeIndicator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/GenericTypeIndicator) is useful for resolving types for generic collections at runtime. Please don't confuse future visitors.